# Rich text editor in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I want to add a rich text editor like ckeditor or tinymce to my Chrome App, but it seems the security policy won't allow it. Is there a way to make ckeditor work in a Chrome App? Otherwise, what rich text editor should I try to implement?

Comment: You could make your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webview which will allow eval, etc.